# Iterate Foreach loop in accordance with first row to get all recors of Table

Tags: c#, for-loop, foreach, dataset

In following code i want read dataset records for only once to avoid database transaction and want to iterate loop in accordance with first row.

```
//InitializeConfig method return dataset which contains 6 records
// i.e. Table with 6 rows and 6 columns

dsConfig = objConfig.InitializeConfig(objConfig, NoOfGates);
foreach (DataRow dr in dsConfig.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    objCR.GetCard(objConfig.iIndex, objConfig.iCRNo, out MainId);
}
```

but I am getting always records from first rows only for each iteration.

Comment: Here I want to read records from Dataset for only one time and want to use it thoroughly.

Comment: Your question and your code are unclear to me but I do notice that you are not using `dr` anywhere in the `foreach` loop.

Comment: Try this : foreach (DataRow dr in dsConfig.Tables[0].AsEnumerable())

Comment: my first column name is GateNo and According to gate no  i.e. Gate 1 ,2 ... i want to iterate the loop....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here No need to use Foreach loop simply I can Iterate for loop for my dataset Object

```
for(i=0; i<dsConfig.Rows.Count; i++)
{
objCR.GetCard(Convert.ToInt32(dsConfig.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[2]), Convert.ToInt32(dsConfig.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[3]), out MainId);
}
```

Because My iIndex and iCRNo parameters from dataset passed to GetCard Method.

Answer (score 0):

The question is rather unclear, but let me expand on the comment from **venerik**. It is pointless to iterate over rows when you're not using them inside the loop body.

```
foreach (DataRow dr in dsConfig.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    // starting from here the variable dr is available
    Console.WriteLine(dr["GateNo"].ToString()) // this should print the value of GateNo column for each row
    objCR.GetCard(objConfig.iIndex, objConfig.iCRNo, out MainId);
}
```